# Replace parenthesis by command

Tags: auctex

In my emacs/AUCTeX setup, when I write `(`, `\left(` or `\(` a corresponding `)`, `\right)`, or `\)` is inserted automatically. 
Is there a way to override this so that inserting `(` produces instead something like `\parent{}` while `\left(` and `\(` work the same way?

Comment: Are you using smartparens for the delimiter completion? If you are, I can update my answer to be more complete.

Comment: Hello zuccs, thanks for the answer. Yes I am using smartparens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```el
(defun insert-open (open arg)
  (setq arg (or arg 0))
  (if (> arg 1)
      (self-insert-command 1)
    (insert open)))

(defun insert-parent (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (call-interactively 
    (lambda (arg) (interactive "p") (insert-open "\\parent{" arg))))

(define-key global-map (kbd "(") 'insert-parent)
```

Create your own versions of `insert-parent` by replacing the "\\parent{" string with what you'd like inserted. Bind that function to appropriate key. Use prefix arg `C-u (` to enter and actual `(`.

**NOTE**: replace `global-map` in the `define-key` function call with whatever mode map you want this to be active in.

## A different approach

The following is adapted from my [org-notes](https://github.com/dwcoates/org-notes) package, which is a package for taking math/latex notes in `org-mode`.  It's still in its infancy and I haven't added it to the Emacs repositories yet, but you're welcome to take a look at it. The code below is modified to work in `latex-mode` or `LaTeX-mode`.

Basically, as mentioned in the comments, use the`borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers` macro to bind context-sensitive `smartparens` pairs to normal keys. E.g.,

```el
(borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers "\\parent{" "}" "(")
```

to bind the `(` to `\parent{` pair so that when region is active, it will wrap region in this pair and move point to the end of the pair. When region is not active, it will insert a normal `(`.

In the `org-notes` package, the `borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers` equivalent will also bind the key inside the `C-c e` prefix, which allows you to wrap the thing before point in the pair, and in addition, wrap the pair in `$` and prompt org-mode to render the latex inline.

```el
(when (not (require 'smartparens nil t))
  (error "borg-notes code requires smartparens. Comment out borg-notes code or install smartparens."))

(defun borg-notes-wrap-with-pair (pair beg end)
  "Insert delimiters corresponding to PAIR at BEG and END.
PAIR is a defined `smartparens' open delimiter."
    (when (and beg end (> end beg))
      (let* ((active-pair (progn (--first (equal (car it) pair)
                                          sp-pair-list))))
        (goto-char end)
        (save-excursion
          (insert (cdr active-pair))
          (goto-char beg)
          (insert (car active-pair))
          (sp--indent-region beg end))
        (forward-char (length (cdr active-pair)))
        (sp-get-thing t))))

(defun borg-notes-sp-wrap-with-pair (pair beg end)
  "Might be superfluous..."
    (or (borg-notes-wrap-with-pair pair beg end)
        (self-insert-command 1) ; returns nil
        ))

(defun borg-notes-latex-wrapper (open close key)
  "Create bindings for OPEN and CLOSE delimiters to KEY.
Wrap previous Latex with OPEN when KEY is pressed following `C-c e' prefix.
Also binds (downcase key) to `org-notes-sp-wrap-with-pair' and (upcase
key) to `org-noteswrap-latex-with-delims-and-render'."
    `(progn
       (sp-pair ,open ,close :actions '(navigate))
       (define-key latex-mode-map (kbd ,key)
         (lambda (beg end)
           (interactive (if (region-active-p)
                            (list (region-beginning)
                                  (region-end))
                          (list nil nil)))
           (borg-notes-sp-wrap-with-pair ,open beg end)))))

(defmacro borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers (open close key)
  "Macro for `org-notes--create-latex-wrapper'."
    (borg-notes-latex-wrapper open close key))

(borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers "\\parent{" "}" "(")
(borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers "\\left{" "}" "p")
(borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers "^{" "}" "i")
(borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers "_{" "}" "u")
(borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers "\\hat{" "}" "h")
(borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers "\\bar{" "}" "b")
(borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers "\\text{" "}" "t")
(borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers "\\tilde{" "}" "e")
(borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers "\\vec{" "}" "v")
(borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers "\\mathbf{" "}" "o")
(borg-notes-create-latex-wrappers "\\mathbb{" "}" "l")
```

Note: for anyone cloning `org-notes`, let me know if there are any problems or questions. The documentation is incomplete.

Comment: Hello zuccs. Thanks for the answer. The problem is that this does not deal with \left( and \( like AUCTeX commands do. That is, inputting "\left(" gives me "\left\parent{"

Comment: Yes, you would need to `C-u (` after `\left`, not `(`. That's why I asked if you were using smartparens. I'll update the answer when I have the time. Also, you would probably want to define a binding for `\left(` anyway, but using smartparens this is much more straight forward, iirc.

Comment: I've made quick adaption of a feature in my `org-notes` package for you. You might find it useful. Basically, it offers a macro that will allow you to bind any key to a function that, when the region is active, will use smartparens to wrap the pair of your choice. For example, mark a region of latex, press `(`, and the region will be wrapped like `\parent{**my code here**}*point here*`. Note that I'm not sure which latex mode you're using, so you may have to change the mode-map in the function as needed. https://gist.github.com/dwcoates/643aba92d786fcc1ea32a364fb22c5b8